# Reading text and Numbers (mixed data type) from a .csv file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, data-import

My data in the csv file is of this form:

```
days of week      date        time(hrs)        visitors
mon            jan 2 2010     900               501 
mon            jan 2 2010    1000               449
mon            jan 2 2010    1100               612
```

The problem is that my csv file progressively gets updated with a new column everytime I run my script and becomes:

```
days of week      date        time(hrs)        visitors     visitors1
mon            jan 2 2010     900               501           200
mon            jan 2 2010    1000               449           100
mon            jan 2 2010    1100               612           300
```

This progressively gets updated to say column (visitors(N)) where N is dynamically changing based on the Matlab script.Now I need a smart way to get the FormatSpecifier to add a "%d" to the textscan FormatSpec parameter everytime I try to read the csv file up till the n-th time of my visitor column

```
fid = fopen('data.csv');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %d %d', 'Delimiter','\t');
fclose(fid);
```

Also, I am open to a smarter or bette way of doing this if possible without using the above method. The whole idea is that I have a mixed data type involved in the csv file to be read.

Comment: You're better off using `readtable`, which will handle the column issue for you.  Note however that with the current file format your column headers will be a bit screwed up and you'll need to deal with amalgamating the dates columns correctly.

Comment: There's yet another limitation with "readtable", at some point I want to be able to join two different tables with no similar keys. I tried using a dummy keys in each row of the table but my table becomes even more ambiguous and making it difficult to work with as there are several limitations with little or no workaround when it comes to IO for csv files. Many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why does `readtable` prevent you from joining tables (with or without a common key)?  `join`, `innerjoin` and `outerjoin` (and their optional inputs) should provide all the functionality you require.  And if they don't then you just extract the data from the tables and do the join as you want.  The point of the use of `readtable` is to overcome the need to specify yourself how many columns there are the file when reading.

Comment: Error is : **Cannot find a common table variable to use as a key variable.**

Comment: Since it's a different topic, open a new question and provide an example.